# Symfony - return non related rows

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have to related tables:

One - device
Two - user

They are connected by the key of user_id in device table.

I need to return all results of users table that are not added in device table.

So, If I have four users in users table and two devices in device table and first is connected to user_1 and second to user_2 result will return other two users.

I think It could be done with leftJoin() but I am getting empty array result.

Code:

```
public function getUsersWithNoDevices()
{
    return $this->getDeviceRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select('d', 'u')
        ->from(User::class, 'u')
        ->where('d.user IS NULL')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Maybe problem is as I meed NOT IN condition as I need to return results that not exists in device table?

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is wrong approach, you should join from user table to devices

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getUsersWithNoDevices()
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('d', 'u')
        ->from('user', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.device', 'd')
        ->where('d.user IS NULL');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I edited my post with your code but still no luck. Empty array.  Edited in the post above. @henryt

Comment: You must start from the user table. Do you have 'u.device' relation?

Comment: I have user_id in device table, not other. @henryt

Comment: maybe problem is as I meed NOT IN condition as I need to return results that not exists in device table? @henryt

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was:

```
return $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->leftJoin('u.device', 'd')
        ->where('d.user IS NULL')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```